# Radix 32 FFT implementation

Tags: fft

Can anyone point me to a c code implementation of Radix 32 FFT. I am trying to write the code myself because I need to add couple of special functions calls inside FFT so please do not point me to libraries. Thanks for answering!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot find an existing C implementation of a radix32 FFT, you might have luck modifying [kissfft](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) to add a radix32 butterfly stage. It has radices 2,3,4,5. The radix4 stage is closest to what you need.